# Looping through a column takes forever

Tags: python, for-loop, spyder

I have the following function

```
condition = (df_sensor_data['Indgang 0103 Duplicate'] == 1) & (df_sensor_data['Indgang 0102 Duplicate'] == 0)
condition_2 = (df_sensor_data['Indgang 0103 Duplicate'] == 0) & (df_sensor_data['Indgang 0102 Duplicate'] >= 15) 

def asdf(sensor_data, condition):
f = sensor_data.loc[condition]
filtered_data = pd.DataFrame()
for _, row in f.iterrows():
    start = row['Date']
    stop = row['Date'].to_pydatetime() + dt.timedelta(minutes=20)
    condition = sensor_data['Date'].between(start, stop, inclusive=True)
    new_data = sensor_data.loc[condition, :].copy()
    filtered_data = pd.concat([filtered_data, new_data], sort=True)
filtered_data = filtered_data.sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)

aggregation = { 'JOBNUM': 'first', 'Non Duplicate 0101' : 'sum' }
return filtered_data.groupby('JOBNUM').agg(aggregation)

f_data = asdf(df_sensor_data, condition)
f_data2 = asdf(df_sensor_data, condition_2)
```

If I run the function using the first condition, everything works well. The f_data dataframe gets created and I can view its contents well. However, if I run the function using the second condition, my Spyder keeps on looping forever.

What could be the cause? The code between the two conditions is not that different, so I don't see what could cause my program to loop forever.

PS: The first condition gets a dataframe of 160 rows, whereas the second one has over 6000. Would that make the difference between the compiling times? Either way, it still looks like it's taking way more than it should have.

Comment: Without having the data available it's difficult to say. However, your second condition may lnclude much more rows, as you have a greater equal condition. Debug and check the size before iterating.

Comment: That is true. The first one has 160 rows, whereas the second one (the one that takes forever) has over 6000. Even though, it should not be normal to take over 6-7 minutes, would it?

Comment: Normally not. The concat method with sorting enabled could be slow. Try to append the data to a csv-file and then use `pd.read_csv`. For large data it's one of the fastest ways.

Comment: Just as a side note: when posting a question, be sure to apply indentation correctly. Your code doesn't work like that (indentation is mandatory in Python code, don't forget that :) )